# Error in 6th Grade Curriculum Book

Tags: triangles, rectangles

[image]This problem appeared in a 6th grade math book for the purpose of finding area, since the two sides are 25cm it is known that the opposite angles are congruent, so they must meet over the midpoint of the 43cm length meaning that the top right triangle couldn't possibly have a length of 24cm from edge to midpoint correct?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: You're correct. I believe the mistake is most likely that the length should be $48$, not $43$. This would make everything consistent, including that the triangle with $2$ dotted sides have lengths forming a $7, 24, 25$ [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Exactly what I was thinking, thanks for confirming!

Comment: @AaronM You are welcome. As far as I can tell, it's the simplest situation because it's only one mistake, with anything else likely needing at least $2$ errors to have been made for all the other values to make sense.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are *forbidden* on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are right, this may be a little mistake, and if you have a teacher you could ask, then I would ask them.